# Autofac - how to register open generics as named or keyed types for use in a factory or using IIndex<,>

Tags: c#, autofac

I am using Net Core 5 and had not yet had a need to use anything other than the built in Dependency Injection. I now have a need to be able to resolve a specific service based on the value selected from a dropdown list of services in a UI.

Out of all the DI containers out there I have decided to delve a bit further into Autofac and think that using either named services and a factory pattern or keyed services will be the way to go but I am running into a bit of difficulty, here is an example;

I have an Interface that look like this

```
public interface IChartDataService<TSource, TTarget>
```

And I have services that have to implement this interface like this

```
public class TreantService : IChartDataService<SourceDto, TargetDto>
```

I am struggling to work out how I am supposed to register these services in the Autofac container.
For named services I have tried to register like this

```
containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MarkOneService)).As(typeof(IChartDataService<,>)).Named<MarkOneService>("markone");

containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MarkTwoService)).As(typeof(IChartDataService<,>)).Named<MarkTwoService>("marktwo");
```

and I try to resolve them like this

```
var service = scope.ResolveNamed("markone", typeof(IChartDataService<,>));
```

also tried it this way

```
var service = scope.ResolveNamed("markone", typeof(IChartDataService<SourceDto,TargetDto>));
```

I cant have registered them correctly as this errors with saying that the service is not registered.

My preferred method would be to use Keyed services, that way I can make use of 'IIndex' but again this is stumping me as to how to register or whether what I am trying to do is even possible.

I am trying to register keyed services like this

```
      containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MarkOneService)).As(typeof(IChartDataService<,>)).Keyed("markone", typeof(IChartDataService<,>));

OR 

containerBuilder.RegisterType<MarkOneService>().As<IChartDataService<,>>().Keyed<IChartDataService<,>>("markone");
```

I am clearly missing something as I cant seem to get the syntax right to be able register correctly. When I do get the registration working I then cant resolve the service because of the open interface.

Also, as I would prefer to use keyed service I dont know how I would be able to get the injected service dictionary. This obviously wont work as it doesn't match my Interface

```
IIndex<string, IChartDataService> serviceDic
```

and this is syntactically invalid according to VS

```
IIndex<string, typeof(IChartDataService<,>)> serviceDic

OR

IIndex<string, IChartDataService<,>> serviceDic
```

I have spent way too much time on this now and I am going round in circles so could do with some tother insight as to where I may be going wrong, anybody any suggestions? can you point me to any examples of what I am trying to acheive please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a bit to unpack here and, while I can kind of explain why things aren't working the way you want, the short answer is you're probably going to have to redesign how you're doing what you're doing. Which is likely not the answer you want, but... it's the answer.

To understand why, we need to ignore Autofac entirely for a moment and just look at the types you're working with.

You have an interface:

```cs
public interface IChartDataService<TSource, TTarget>
```

As an open generic, this could be `IChartDataService<string, Exception>` or it could be `IChartDataService<object, object>` or anything else. (Yes, I get there may be constraints, but stick with me - as an open generic, those types could change all over the place.) So when you talk about `IChartDataService<,>` in that form, that's what you're saying: "The open generic where anything could be in either of those type parameter spots."

Now, *sometimes* folks will create an equally generic implementation, like:

```cs
public class ChartDataService<TSource, TTarget>
  : IChartDataService<TSource, TTarget>
```

Taking a step back to Autofac, [that's what `RegisterGeneric` is for](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components) - to handle the open generic *implementations*. *If you had* this sort of thing, you'd register like:

```cs
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ChartDataService<,>))
       .As(typeof(IChartDataService<,>));
```

In that case, you're actually registering an open generic.

However, *that's not what you have*. You have types that implement an interface - a very specific interface. Let's look at what you have:

```cs
public class TreantService : IChartDataService<SourceDto, TargetDto>
```

Based on that, we see:

- `TreantService` isn't a generic at all. That class, itself, has no generic type parameters.
- `TreantService` implements a *closed generic interface*. Put another way, you *can* cast a `TreantService` to an `IChartDataService<SourceDto, TargetDto>` but you *can't* cast it to `IChartDataService<string, Exception>` or anything else.

For all intents and purposes, `IChartDataService<SourceDto, TargetDto>` in this case is no different than any other standard interface like `IComparable` or something. Once it's a closed generic like this, *it's just a type*.

So let's say you have a bunch of these, with a bunch of different DTO types:

```cs
public class FirstService
  : IChartDataService<FirstSource, FirstTarget> { }
public class SecondService
  : IChartDataService<SecondSource, SecondTarget> { }
public class ThirdService
  : IChartDataService<ThirdSource, ThirdTarget> { }
```

Sure, they all implement `IChartDataService<TSource, TTarget>` but they're closed generics. You can't cast them to the same underlying interface.

Now let's say you want to store them all in a `List<T>`. What would the `T` be there to make that work?

It'd be `object` - the only common base class they have. You'd have to use `List<object>`. Which, yeah, sucks, but as you found there's no such thing as a `List<IChartDataService<,>>`, or a dictionary that would hold an open generic as the value. If you think about it, that makes sense, because let's say you wanted to pull them back out:

```cs
// Pretend this is a thing.
var list = new List<IChartDataService<,>>();
foreach(var item in  list)
{
  // What type is `item` in this loop?
  // How does the compiler know what types
  // to fill in for the open generic? It's
  // not a dynamic language, so you can't
  // "switch types" on every loop iteration.
}
```

Hopefully at this point you can start seeing some of the problems with what you're trying to do, and it's not a problem with Autofac - it's a problem with how the interfaces are designed and how you want to consume them.

This is why you'll sometimes see non-generic interfaces like `System.IEnumerable` *and* generic counterparts like `System.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`. `IEnumerable` for the things that are common *regardless* of the generic type parameters and the generic to make things strongly typed.

I can't really tell you how to solve the problem because how you approach it will largely be dependent on your application code and what exactly you're doing. But, a recap of what I've covered here is where I'd personally start if it was me:

- **Ignore Autofac**. Try to design things that you could mock out entirely in a unit test (like having a constructor parameter with the right types that can simulate what you'll actually see). If you can't get it to compile or work with all your types without Autofac, Autofac is not going to magically somehow make it work.
- **Consider a common non-generic interface**. Sort of like that `IEnumerable` vs `IEnumerable<T>` difference. It may be that for *implementation* purposes it's nice to have that generic, but the actual common methods that get called don't require the generic (or maybe could take `object`?).

Comment: I couldn't have asked for a more concise explanation than this, thank you very much you have certainly given me clarity on where I am going wrong. Time for a bit of a redesign me thinks!